# Update value in one column based on criteria from multiple other columns in r

Tags: r, multiple-columns, conditional-formatting

**R Version 3.3.2(2016-10-31)**

**R Studio Version 1.0.136**

**Platform: X86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)**

**Data frame**

```
Subject Drug Death_3MONTHS, Death_6MONTHS, Death_12MONTHS
1        1       0            0               NaN
2        1       1            NaN             NaN
3        2       0            0                0
4        2       0            0                1
```

`NaN` - missing value = lost follow up

**Questions**

I want to create another two columns

1. create Column named  `1 year mortality`

   if `Death_3months`, or `Death_6months`, or `Death_12 months = 1`,

   fill it with `1`, else fill it with `0`
2. create column named `Time to Event`

   if `Death_3months` =  `NaN` fill it with`0`

   if `Death_3months` = `1` fill it with `3`,

   if `Death_3months` = `0` Check `Death_6months` column

   if `Death_6months` =  `NaN` fill it with `3`

   if `Death_6months` = `1` fill it with `6`,

   if `Death_6months` = `0`Check `Death_12months` column

   if `Death_12months` =  `NaN` fill it with `6`

   if `Death_12months` = `1` fill it with `12`,

   if `Death_12months` = `0` fill it with `12`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have to use basic [`if-then-else`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_if_else_statement.htm) block for multiple conditions.

Comment: What doe "Check" mean? Use the value from that column in the current column?

Comment: i was able to solve the first problem using the below code 

    `dataframe$1yearmortality <- ifelse(data.frame$Death_3Months/ data.frame$Death_6Months/ data.frame$Death_12Months == "1", 1, 0)`

Comment: @neilfws "Check" mean to look at another column named "Death_6Months"

Comment: I figured out how to answer the second question using "if else" function 

Thank you Guys sorry I'm novice to this excuse me if there are any errors 

Basically i used the below mentioned code 

`d.fl$timetoevent <- ifelse(d.f$Death3mon == "NaN", 0, ifelse(d.f$Death3mon == "1", 3, ifelse(d.f$Death6mon == "NaN", 3, ifelse(d.f$Death6mon == "1", 6, ifelse(d.f$Death12mon == "NaN", 6, 12)))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

#initilize sample data.table
DT <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4), c(1,1,2,2),c(0,1,0,0),c(0,NaN,0,0),c(NaN,NaN,0,1))
colnames(DT) <- c("Subject","Drug","Death_3Months","Death_6months","Death_12months")

#Add row together using death columns and exclude NA's
DT[, "1 year mortality" := rowSums(.SD, na.rm=TRUE), .SDcols = 3:5]

#run through ifelse logic as described
DT[, "Time to Event" := ifelse(!is.finite(Death_3Months), 0,
                               ifelse(Death_3Months == 1, 3,
                                      ifelse(!is.finite(Death_6months), 3, 
                                             ifelse(Death_6months == 1, 6,
                                                    ifelse(!is.finite(Death_12months), 6, 12)))))]

DT

> DT
   Subject Drug Death_3Months Death_6months Death_12months 1 year mortality Time to Event
1:       1    1             0             0            NaN                0             6
2:       2    1             1           NaN            NaN                1             3
3:       3    2             0             0              0                0            12
4:       4    2             0             0              1                1            12
```